# Rudin exercise 2.27

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

Does the below proof for exercise 2.27 look right?  In particular the last part about E containing at most countably many points not in P.  Thank you.

Q. Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, $E$ is uncountable, and $P$ is the set of condensation points of $E$.  Prove that $P$ is perfect and that there are at most countably many points in $E$ that are not in $P$.

A. Suppose P is the set of all condensation points of a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^k$.  Suppose P is not closed. Then there exists a limit point $p \in P^c$.  But this implies that $\exists$ some $0 < s < r$ such that $N_s(p_n) \subset N_r(p) $ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}\Rightarrow N_r(p)$ is uncountable which is impossible.  Hence P is closed.  Suppose $\exists p \in P$ that is isolated.  Then $\exists$ some $r>0$ such that $N_r(p) \bigcap P = {p}$.  Choose a $x \in N_{r/2}(p)$.  Then $\exists 0<s<r/2$ such that $p \in N_s(p) \subset N_{r/2}(x) \subset N_r(p)$. Hence $N_{r/2}(x)$ is uncountable and $x \in P$ which is contrary to $p$ being isolated. So $P$ is perfect.  Now consider $E \bigcap P^c$, which must be open in $E$ since $P^c$ is open.  Since $\mathbb{R}^k$ is separable, it has a countable base $\lbrace V_a \rbrace$ such that if $x \in P^c$, then for some $a$, $x \in V_a \subset P^c$.  Now the $V_a \bigcap E \bigcap P^c$ is at most countable for if not then $V_a$ contains a condensation point, and since the $\lbrace V_a \rbrace$ are countable so must $E \bigcap P^c$.

Comment: In lines two and three of your answer, you refer to a point $p_n$, but you haven't introduced the sequence $(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. You may also want to say that $p\in P^c$ is a limit point of $P$, rather than simply saying it is a limit point.

Comment: The definition of a condensation point is that every neighborhood of the point is uncountable. That means that to show $x\in P$, one has to show that $N_r(x)$ is uncountable for every $r$, and not just for a single $r$. But two times in your answer you have said that if a point has one uncountable neighborhood, it is a condensation point. For example, in line 5 of your answer, you said "$N_{r/2}(x)$ is uncountable and $x\in P$." But $x\in P$ does not follow from $N_{r/2}(x)$ being uncountable.

Comment: In order to know that $x\in P$, you need $\forall r>0$, $N_r(x)$ is uncountable, not $\exists r>0$ such that $N_r(x)$ is uncountable.

Comment: @user95250 thank you for these helpful comments